# can you navigate between widgets with only one scaffold

Tags: flutter, navigation, android-widget, scaffold

I have created a widget with a scaffold and called a widget in it as

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Everything Store"),
      ),
      body: Register(),
    );
  }
}
```

the Register component doesn't have a scaffold in it, but when I try to navigate from the Register widget to another one that also doesn't have a scaffold too, so I used

```
 onPressed: () => {
                Navigator.of(context)
                    .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => login_page()))
              },
```

I got an error as " No Material widget found. "
So is there a way to have one scaffold or should I make a scaffold for each widget?

Answer (score -1):

The scaffold is one of the main widgets that helps you build up the UI screen on a device but a screen doesn't necessarily need it. The error that you are getting it might be because you are not passing the Widget class correctly.
Try to replace login_page() with the class name like so Register().

Comment: the navigation function is called in the Register() class and the login_page() is the class I am trying to navigate to , you get me ?

Comment: Update it only works when I make a scaffold in the login_page() class, so the issue is that when I navigate it leaves both widgets the one with the scaffold and the one inside of it which I am calling the navigation in

Comment: Can you at least wrap the login_page widget inside a Material widget? As a suggestion, you should name your widget classes using Camel notation, also page level widgets should try to be inside a Scaffold.